# How add JPanel in Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

In my question, this is `Refectoring Class`. In this class, i'm using `JPanel` for adding button by a separate  Method `panel()` and Call in the `RefectClass` Constactor.

```
public class RefectClass extends JFrame {
    JButton btnHome,btnBack;
    JPanel btnContainer;

    public RefectClass(){
        super("Title Here");
        setSize(350,300);
        add(this.panel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void panel(){

        btnContainer=new JPanel();
        btnHome=new JButton("Home");
        btnBack=new JButton("Back");

        btnContainer.add(btnHome);
        btnContainer.add(btnBack);

    }

}
```

Now how to add panel to JFrame? it gives an error, when i try to use it. I'm unable use to the `panel()` Mehtod.

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel() method doesn't return anything so you can't write

> add(this.panel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);

try

```
this.panel();
add(this.btnContainer,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanx now code working please explain these Statements which are above mention you.thanx again

Comment: In your panel method you are setting the instance field btnContainer. Only after executing panel() you may add this field to the frame. Note though, that it would perhaps be a more elegant solution to return the field from the method as suggested by others...

Answer (score 2):

Your panel() method returns void - it should return your newly created JPanel instead such that you can add it to the JFrame:

```
public JPanel panel(){

    btnContainer=new JPanel();
    btnHome=new JButton("Home");
    btnBack=new JButton("Back");

    btnContainer.add(btnHome);
    btnContainer.add(btnBack);
    return btnContainer;

}
```

Let me point out, though, that this is a very unusual approach. You shouldn't have to initialize a member in a public method that returns the newly initialized member when the method is actually just needed inside the class. Imagine a client calling the panel method multiple times from outside (since it is public). BtnContainer, btnHOme and BtnBack would be overriden but they wouldn't appear on the screen.
The method seems fairy simply - why not just include it directly in your constructor?
Or at least make the method `private`.

Comment: Because i'm working on Interafce of the Student Form(In JDBC) Only Swing Pushing me back .all work is done.